# How to sort by time an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, sorting, time

What's the best approach to sort by time an array of hashes?

```
[
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature", :time=>"0m2.004s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"addition.feature", :time=>"0m22.031s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"division.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"}
]
```

So, I'm expecting to have it sorted by time (in descending order) like:

```
[
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"addition.feature", **:time=>"0m22.031s**"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"division.feature", **:time=>"0m3.004s**"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature", **:time=>"0m3.004s**"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature", **:time=>"0m2.004s**"}
]
```

The times are `String`s, so do I need to convert it to `Int` before? Or is there any way to sort it?

Comment: What you have are not valid Ruby expressions.

Comment: Convert it to int? Do you want to ignore the fractional parts? You need to make your intention clear. The correct answer differs depending on that. I voted to close since you have not made that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.sort_by{|h| h[:time].scan(/[\d.]+/).map(&:to_f)}.reverse
```

Comment: Good to know that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ary = [
    {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature", :time=>"0m2.004s"},
    {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"addition.feature", :time=>"0m22.031s"},
    {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"division.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"},
    {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"}
]

ary = ary.sort_by do |hash|
  match = /(\d+)m([\d.]+)s/.match hash[:time]
  -(match[1].to_f * 60 + match[2].to_f)
end

ary.each { |hash| p hash }
```

**output**

```
{:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"addition.feature", :time=>"0m22.031s"}
{:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"}
{:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"division.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"}
{:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature", :time=>"0m2.004s"}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = [
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature", :time=>"0m2.004s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"addition.feature", :time=>"0m22.031s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers", :scenario_line=>5, :feature_file=>"division.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"},
  {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers", :scenario_line=>6, :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature", :time=>"0m3.004s"}
]

arr.sort_by{|i| i[:time].scan(/\d+/).map{|i| -i.to_i}} 
# => [{:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Sum of many numbers",
#      :scenario_line=>6,
#      :feature_file=>"addition.feature",
#      :time=>"0m22.031s"},
#     {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Subtract two different numbers",
#      :scenario_line=>6,
#      :feature_file=>"subtraction.feature",
#      :time=>"0m3.004s"},
#     {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Regular numbers",
#      :scenario_line=>5,
#      :feature_file=>"division.feature",
#      :time=>"0m3.004s"},
#     {:scenario_name=>"Scenario: Two different numbers",
#      :scenario_line=>5,
#      :feature_file=>"multiplication.feature",
#      :time=>"0m2.004s"}]
```